# Android: How to change between finger and spen when drawing

Tags: android, canvas

I have developed a drawing app.
Now I need to add a button that, when it is ON, it only allows drawing on the canvas using the spen and when its off it only allows drawing with fingers on the canvas.

My goal is to avoid messing a drawing when I am using the spen and my hand touches the canvas.

Thanks

Comment: Hi did you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in `MotionEvent` object in method `getToolType(int)`

This method returns one of values below:

```
TOOL_TYPE_UNKNOWN
TOOL_TYPE_FINGER
TOOL_TYPE_STYLUS
TOOL_TYPE_MOUSE
```

There are constants from  `MotionEvent` class.

So you can check the tool type and your button state in some condition which defines that you can draw on canvas.

Comment: If I helped you please accept my answer :) If not ask me I will explain you more